# understanding the measurement scales in the survey

Tags: cross-validation, scales

I asked this question in another sit and someone in the comment told, this is a right sit to ask this question. Please  be patient with me , this is my first time asks in the sit.

Nowadays, it is very common in the survey to find a statement with scales measurement agrees or disagree, etc. Let's consider a survey about online classes,  take this statement as an example:

Do you like online classes or in-person classes: strongly agree $(5)$, agree $(4)$, not sure $(3)$, disagree strongly$(2)$, disagree $(1)$.

My question:

> what do these numbers represent? How can I understand the difference between a person chose strongly agree and a person who chose not sure for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is [Likert scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale). the answers are usually meant to represent ordinal categories, i.e. "strongly agree" is not twice stronger than "agree" when compared to "not sure", though it is stronger indeed

Comment: Aksakal. Thank you for your answer. I think I should read likert scales to understand this better. Right?

Comment: yes, learn about their usage